# Apache - Why my apache user is a number?

Tags: apache-2.2, users

```
$ ps aux | grep httpd

1003     22806  0.0  0.3  17624  7684 ?        S    May25   0:00 /opt/web/apache/bin/httpd -k start
1003      4834  0.0  0.3  17624  7684 ?        S    May28   0:00 /opt/web/apache/bin/httpd -k start
1003      5299  0.0  0.3  17740  7804 ?        S    May28   0:00 /opt/web/apache/bin/httpd -k start
1003      5503  0.0  0.3  17624  7684 ?        S    May28   0:00 /opt/web/apache/bin/httpd -k start
1003      5875  0.0  0.3  17624  7684 ?        S    May28   0:00 /opt/web/apache/bin/httpd -k start
1003      5970  0.0  0.3  17624  7684 ?        S    May28   0:00 /opt/web/apache/bin/httpd -k start
1003      6062  0.0  0.3  17624  7672 ?        S    May28   0:00 /opt/web/apache/bin/httpd -k start
1003      6245  0.0  0.3  17624  7684 ?        S    May28   0:00 /opt/web/apache/bin/httpd -k start
1003      6338  0.0  0.3  17624  7672 ?        S    May28   0:00 /opt/web/apache/bin/httpd -k start
1003     24091  0.0  0.3  17624  7764 ?        S    May30   0:00 /opt/web/apache/bin/httpd -k start
```

My apache user seems to be 1003, isn't it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ps` uses the UID number if the user name is over a certain number of characters (probably longer than 7 or 8 chars in your case).

From the man pages,

```
   euser      EUSER   effective user name. This will be the textual
                      user ID, if it can be obtained and the field width
                      permits, or a decimal representation otherwise. The n option
                      can be used to force the decimal representation.
                      (alias uname, user).
```

So depending on how wide the column output for user name is, your user name is probably too long.

Use `grep ":1003:" /etc/passwd` to see the user name and see how long it is.

Comment: True. However `grep "User " /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` gives `User www-data` ...

Comment: So in that case, it's probably showing the UID for everything over 7 characters in length.  It's still 'right', it's just ps that's changing the display output.  What does `grep ":1003:" /etc/passwd` return.

Comment: Forgot to mention that `grep ":1003:" /etc/passwd` gives `ftpwestmill:x:1003:1002:FTP:/home/httpd/html/default:/bin/false`

Comment: Then your httpd processes are running as ftpwestmill.  You need to raise another question to solve why.  I suggest you accept this as answered (if you feel it is) since it explains why it shows 1003 not ftpwestmill, and then raise a second question asking why your apache config is apparently being ignored.

Comment: You are right. I was waiting the 10 minutes to check it.

Comment: @EightBitTony: Why are you so sure your grep proves the id for httpd processes? If the server is using NIS/LDAP/something else, it might very well be those override /etc/passwd.

Comment: @JannePikkarainen Occam's razor.